# list index out of range,помогите пожайлуста!

Tags: python, list, index

```
w = [int(x) for x in input().split()]
c = [int(x) for x in input().split()]
r = [int(x) for x in input().split()]
d = [0] * 3
for i in range(3):
    d[i] = c[i] * r[i] - w[i]
mx = max(d)
if mx <= 0:
    print(0)
else:
    for i in range(3):
        if mx == d[i]:
            print(i + 1, end=' ')
```

Comment: Нет такой ошибки - после ввода трех символов через пробел нажимайте ентер и вводите следующие

Answer (score 0):

Вместо `input.split()`, напишите `input.split(" ")` и вводите 3 числа через пробел, затем нажимайте Enter.

метод str.split() принимает на вход строку A, через которую нужно делить исходную строку B, в вашем случае строка A - это пробел. Вы не указали A.

А еще лучше вызывайте функцию, определенную следующим образом

```
def input_list():
    l = input().split(" ");
    if (len(l) != 3)
        print(u"Неверное количество введенных чисел")
    return l
```

Comment: `" "`  указывать не обязательно